# Celery both workers getting same task even if theres different queue and routing key defined

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, celery, celery-task

I have settings in my celery config

```
CELERY_QUEUES = (
                    Queue('oracle', Exchange('exchange1'), routing_key='bitch'),
                    Queue('neo',  Exchange('exchange2'),   routing_key='check'),
                    Queue('morpheus',  Exchange('exchange3'),  routing_key='fromlocal'),
                    Queue('trinity', routing_key='getme.*'),
                    Queue('xxx', routing_key='showme.#'),
                    ),

CELERY_ROUTES={
                    'whois.tasks.parsewhois':{
                        'queue':'trinity',
                        'routing_key':'getme.*',
                        },
                    'whois.tasks.fororacle':{
                        'queue':'xxx',
                        'routing_key':'showme.#',
                        },

                    },
```

And i run my 2 workers as

```
celery -A jarvis worker -l info -Q trinity --hostname=trinity@%h
celery -A jarvis worker -l info -Q xxx --hostname=xxx@%h
```

Now as i send a task to my worker

```
parsewhois.apply_async(args['20596696'],queue='trinity',routing_key='getme')
```

The above task goes only to the trinity queue, but as i run the command below:

```
fororacle.apply_async(args=[10],queue='xxx',routing_key='showme')
```

now this task goes to both trinity queue and xxx queue, both get the same tasks and operates same task. 
Is it that i'm not getting difference of topic and direct or is my configuration just wrong. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try execute celery commands with different worker names:

```
celery -A jarvis worker -l info -Q trinity --hostname=trinity@%h -n worker1.%h
celery -A jarvis worker -l info -Q xxx --hostname=xxx@%h -n worker2.%h
```

Hope that will help

Comment: Your answer is ridiculous if you don't know much please see how to name a worker from a document `You can also start multiple workers on the same machine. If you do so be sure to give a unique name to each individual worker by specifying a host name with the --hostname|-n argument` [http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#starting-the-worker]

Comment: Thank's. Edited. I meant try execute workers with different names. erred through quick response :)